# Finalize the magic square generator

Tags: c++, algorithm, generator

This code that runs only for odd N. The problem is that there are no ideas how to add support for even values N

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the size of the magic square - ";
    cin >> n;

    int **matrix = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    int nsqr = n * n;
    int i = 0, j = n / 2;

    for (int k = 1; k <= nsqr; ++k)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = k;
        i--;
        j++;
        if (k % n == 0)
        {
            i += 2;
            --j;
        }
        else
        {
            if (j == n)
            {
                j -= n;
            }
            else if (i < 0)
            {
                i += n;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nMagic square size - " << n << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;

    system("pause >> null");
    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful for tips on troubleshooting.

If i'm not mistaken, the problem is in this line:

```
int i = 0, j = n / 2;
```

But i don't know how to change the code to support even values

Comment: Check for even values using `value % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You need a totally different algorithm: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76411/how-to-construct-magic-squares-of-even-order

Comment: can you write: `matrix[-2][0]`?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you meant **normal** magic square (where the number are restricted to 1,2..n^2)

First of all, it's impposible to construct such magic square for n=2.

2nd, you would need an whole new algorithm for it, which is much more complicated. The problem (constructing magic square for **any** even number) is solved [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.0948.pdf) and while there isn't any psaudo code there, the implementation from the explenation is quite straightforward (long one though).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
i = 0;
int j = n / 2;

for (int k = 1; k <= nsqr; ++k)
{
    matrix[i][j] = k;
    i--;
}
```

look how you decrement i inside the loop and making it as an index of the array so:

```
 matrix[-3][j] = k; // will be in your code
```

you are messing deliberately with the indexes of the array

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on my question in [this artcile](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html)
I made full revision my algorithm based on this article. Later posted listing the resulting program